# Is accessing a member of an unaligned union undefined behavior even if the member being accessed is sufficiently aligned?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, unions, memory-alignment

In C bad things can happen if I try to access a type through a pointer that is not aligned:

```
int x[2]; // Assuming CHAR_BIT == 8 && sizeof(int) == 4
*(int *)((char *)x+1) = 10; /* Undefined behavior due to unaligned pointer dereference
    even though there are no out of bounds accesses */
```

However what if the type in question is a `union` but I am only accessing a member of the `union` that does not have the alignment requirements?

```
union X {
    int i;
    char c[4];
} x[2];
((union X *)((char *)x+1))->i = 10; /* I am guessing this is still undefined behavior
    because accessing an unaligned int through a union does not make a difference as far as I know */
```

But would the following invoke undefined behavior?

```
((union X *)((char *)x+1))->c[0] = 10;
```

I am in doubt because on one hand I am dereferencing a `union` pointer via the `->` operator and the `union` has alignment requirements because of the `int` field, but on the other hand, I am not touching the `int` field. So does that result in any unaligned pointer access violations?

Comment: the union has alignment requirements -- it has to have the maximum alignment of any of the member types. So `(union X *)((char *)x+1)` is not a valid pointer to the union.

Comment: @Barmar So yes, the code invokes UB.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read through the full question, I didn't realize your question was about accessing the char array.

Comment: I think it's technically UB, but in practice it should work on most normal architectures.

Comment: @Barmar So is creating the *pointer* where the UB happens, or the act of *dereferencing* it?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting question... My guess (and it's *only* a guess) is that UB - due to alignment requirements -  is not possible, here, But, in terms of syntax, then there may be UB.

Comment: Or, rather, your union ***does*** have the alignment requirements. How can it not have?

Comment: @user16217248, `(union X *)((char *)x+1)` is UB when the alignment of `union X` is not met.  Rest of code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast causes undefined behavior. From [C23](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) 6.3.2.3(7)

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting
> pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

Since `(union X *)((char *)x+1))` is not correctly aligned for the union, the second sentence applies. It doesn't matter whether you actually dereference it.

Comment: So I can pretend an unaligned pointer in and of itself is a trap representation.

Comment: If that's how you want to think of it, sure.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this will come up in actual code, so why do you need to think about it at all?

Comment: If you want to know, it came up in some complicated octree code ***similar*** to what I have in [this CR.SE question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/287229/264812). Basically I was wondering if I could make a certain variable a `Node8 *` or if I would have to make it a `uint16_t *`, if I would potentially have to store a non 8 byte aligned pointer there, and access the first `uint16_t` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Clang will sometimes generate nonsensical code in situations where a pointer to a union type receives an address which is not aligned for all of the members thereof, even if code makes no use of any members whose alignment requirements are not satisfied.  When targeting the Cortex-M0 (which does not support unaligned word accesses) for example, the function:

```
union fnord { unsigned char b[4]; unsigned w; };
void test(union fnord *restrict p1, union fnord *restrict p2)
{
    p1->b[0] = p2->b[0];
    p1->b[1] = p2->b[1];
    p1->b[2] = p2->b[2];
    p1->b[3] = p2->b[3];
}
```

will be processed as a single word load and store.  I don't think the authors of the Standard to make it impossible to have a type which could be used to access objects with minimal alignment requirements, but presumed capable of aliasing objects with coarser requirements, but the way clang interprets it does.

Comment: Which means that, assuming Clang is a conforming implementation, the answer is yes, doing that is UB.

Comment: @user16217248: Given that clang is only conforming in the sense that nothing an otherwise-conforming implementation does when fed any program which does not exercise any of the translation limits given in N1570 5.2.4.1 could render it non-conforming, your inference doesn't hold.

Comment: I don't understand. If a conforming compiler generates nonsensical code for a language construct, then the language construct must have undefined behavior. Otherwise it would be generating nonsensical code for a defined language construct, which would make it non-conforming.

Comment: @user16217248: All the Standard requires is that there exist at least one possible program that exercises the translation limits given in N1570 5.2.4.1 (or corresponding parts of earlier standards) which an implementation processes correctly.  According to the published C99 Rationale, "While a deficient implementation could probably contrive a program that meets this requirement, yet still succeed in being useless, the C89 Committee felt that such ingenuity would probably require more work than making something useful."  There are cases where the authors of clang and gcc deliberately ignore...

Comment: ...parts of the Standard that are inconvenient, on the assumption that nobody will care about the corner cases described therein, so the fact that clang and gcc optimizers process a program in a manner inconsistently with sequentially performing all of the individual steps described therein does not imply that the program's behavior isn't defined in the language the Standard was chartered to describe, or that it isn't defined by the Standard.

Comment: @user16217248: The Rationale also notes that "The belief was that it is simply not practical to provide a specification which is strong enough to be useful, but which still allows for real-world problems such as bugs."  Even if the Standard would unambiguously specify the behavior of a program, the Committee didn't think it should classify a buggy compiler that processes the program nonsensically as "non-conforming".  See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf for more information.